# Searching for item in two dictionaries and returning result based on the match

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, search

```
co_1 = {'a1': [(1, 1)], 'b1': [(0, 4), (0, 0), (4, 0)]}
co_2 = {'a2': [(2, 2)], 'b2': [(1, 5), (1, 2), (5, 1)]}

position = (x, y)
```

How do I check if the position(e.g. (1, 5)) is present in the values of the two dictionaries 'co_1 and co_2'.

So far I have:

```
for key, value in co_1.items():
    if position in value:
        return (statement1)
for key, value in co_1.items():
    if position in value:
        return(statement2)
#if position not in either value --> return None
```

Is there a way to clean this up so I can search for position in both dictionaries together and then have an if-else statement: if position present in values (co_1 or co_2) return (statement) else return None.

Such As:

```
for key, value in co_1.items() and co_2.items():
    if position in value in co_1.items():
        return statement1
    elif position in value in co_2.items():
        return statement2
    else:
        return None
#example if position = (2, 2) --> return statement2
#exmaple if position = (3, 1) --> return None
```

Comment: In what way is your new code "cleaner"?

Comment: Are the dictionary keys always the same for both dicts? And if both keys contain `position` what do you return?

Comment: `next((s for s, d in zip((statement1, statement2), (co_1, co_2)) for v in d.values() if position in v), None)` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the keys are not relevant here – you could just build a set of tuples from both dictionaries.

```
co_1_set = {y for x in co_1 for y in co_1[x] } 
co_2_set = {y for x in co_2 for y in co_2[x] }
```

Now, a membership test is as simple as an `if-elif` statement:

```
def foo(position):
    if position in co_1_set:
        return statement1

    elif position in co_2_set:
        return statement2
```

You'll want to perform the `set` constructions as little as possible - ideally only when the dictionary contents change.

---

If both your dictionaries contain `position`, this code returns `statement1` only. If you want something different, you'll need to make changes as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Is this considered 'better' then having the two 'for' statements in my original query?  I'm a little new to python and haven't quite gotten to list comprehension. Any chance you could also include an extended version so I can see how it's done.

Comment: @turtlepower it is better, because you cache your results for fast access, basically. It's like doing: S = set(); for x in co_1: for y in co_1[x]: S.add(y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flattened values of each dict like below:

```
co_1 = {'a1': [(1, 1)], 'b1': [(0, 4), (0, 0), (4, 0)]}
co_2 = {'a2': [(2, 2)], 'b2': [(1, 5), (1, 2), (5, 1)]}

def check_position(pos):
    if pos in [item for sublist in co_1.values() for item in sublist]:
        return 'statement1'
    elif pos in [item for sublist in co_2.values() for item in sublist]:
        return 'statement2'
    else:
        return None

pos1 = (2, 2)
pos2 = (0, 4)

print(check_position(pos1))  # Output: statement2
print(check_position(pos2))  # Output: statement1
```

Answer (score 0):

another way: `sum(pos in v for v in arg.values())` is a membership test returning `0`, which == `False` when `pos` is not found

used below as the conditional in a list comprehension that returning the `enumerate` index of the input `*args`

```
co_1 = {'a1': [(1, 1)], 'b1': [(0, 4), (0, 0), (4, 0)]}
co_2 = {'a2': [(2, 2)], 'b2': [(1, 5), (1, 2), (5, 1)]}
pos = (1, 5)


def q(pos, *args):
    return [i for i, arg in enumerate(args)
            if sum(pos in v for v in arg.values())]


q(pos, co_1, co_2)
Out[184]: [1]

q((0, 0), co_1, co_2)
Out[185]: [0]

q((0, 10), co_1, co_2)
Out[186]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can that using 2 Boolean variable

```
co_1 = {'a1': [(1, 1)], 'b1': [(0, 4), (0, 0), (4, 0)]}
co_2 = {'a2': [(1, 2)], 'b2': [(1, 5), (1, 2), (5, 1)]}
position = (1,1)

tco1=False
tco2=False
for key, value in co_1.items():
    if position in value:
        tco1=True

for key, value in co_2.items():
    if position in value:
        tco2=True
if tco1==True:
    print("Statement 1") #Or return Statement 1
elif tco2==True:
    print("Statement 2") #Or return Statement 2
else :
    print("None") #Or return None
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using generator:

```
def search(item, co_1, co_2):
    co_1_values = co_1.values()
    co_2_values = co_2.values()
    for value in list(co_1_values) + list(co_2_values):
        yield 'statement1' if item in value in co_1_values else ''
        yield 'statement2' if item in value in co_2_values else ''
```

In this case you will recieve all found statements.

If you need just first occurance:

```
for item in search((1, 1), co_1, co_2):
    if item.strip():
        print(item)
        break
```

Comment: Why search combined list of items, only to ignore the keys, AFTER you have already extracted all of the values?  And when you find a match, *search* to find which set it came from?  In what way is this better than the original code?